# Why did so many cats appear in this scene?

Tags: plot-explanation, silence

In [Silence](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0490215/), why did so many cats appear in this scene?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [**How to Ask**](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: The question seemed pretty clear to me, even before the edit. "Why so many cats?" Not much else to add to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the town was abandoned, the cats were allowed to reproduce and go feral without any people around to stop (or fix) them.  There apparently were no predators above the cat level, so they had carte blanche to grow wild, as it were.